# Need to make an image responsive in liquid file on shopify

Tags: html, css, json, shopify, liquid

I've coded up a new section in my shopify back-end
The section basically gives you the option to add image(s)  to a page , I'm able to see the images
on the front-end , however the image is aligned to the right at the moment

what i require is that the image(s) should by default expand to the width of the visible screen - basically making it responsive

**below is the code of my "image.liquid" file for this section**

```
{%for block in section.blocks %}
    
   {{ block.settings.image_1 | img_url: "1250x" | img_tag }}

{% endfor %}
{% schema %}
  {
  "name": "Images_N",
  "blocks" : [ 
    {
      "type" : "image",
        "name" : "Image block",
        "settings": [
                        {
                              "type": "image_picker",
                              "id": "image_1",
                              "label": "Images_N"    
                        }
                    ] 
    }
        
    ],
    "presets" : [
                {
                  "category" : "image",
                  "name"  : "Images_N"
                }
    ]
  
}
{% endschema %}
```

**below is the code of my "product.aplustemplate.liquid" file for template file in which i'm using the above section file**

```
{% section 'product-template' %}
{% section 'image' %}
```

Link to the product on which I've applied the template
https://store.bhawar.com/products/garmin-test-product?_pos=3&_sid=87e89b7ab&_ss=r&variant=45005860438308

I'm trying to make the image responsive

Answer (score 0):

To have a responsive image that takes up the entire width of the screen, here is how I would have done it:

```
<style>
  .media {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .media > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center center;
  }
</style>

{%- for block in section.blocks -%}
  <div class="media" style="padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: block.settings.image_1.aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;">
    {{ block.settings.image_1 | image_url: width: block.settings.image_1.width | image_tag: loading: 'lazy', widths: '450, 660, 900, 1320, 1800, 2136, 2400, 3600, 7680', sizes: '100vw' }}
  </div>
{%- endfor -%}
```

- The style is to be put in a css file if possible.
- The padding-bottom on the `div.media` is used to have a block that takes the whole width of the screen while having the same ratio as the image.
- The image is in absolute position to take the height and width of the `div.media`.
- The `loading: lazy` attribute is used to indicate that the image must be loaded only when it enters the viewport (which increases the loading speed of the page).
- The `widths` attribute is used to indicate the sizes available for this image. I put the most important sizes according to me.
- The `sizes` attribute is used to indicate the size of the image on the screen, here 100vw (view width).

You can consult the documentation of the [image_url](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters/image_url) filter and the [image_tag](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters/image_tag) filter.